# Cannot get Spring to export annotations to JMX

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I can't for the life of me get Spring to export metadata about my JMX beans.

I have Spring configured as follows:

```
<bean id="attributeSource" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource"/>

<bean id="namingStrategy" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.naming.MetadataNamingStrategy">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="assembler" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
    <property name="attributeSource" ref="attributeSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
    <property name="autodetect" value="true"/>
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
    <property name="assembler" ref="assembler"/>
</bean>
```

I have an MXBean interface defined like this:

```
@ManagedResource
public interface MyMXBean {
    @ManagedOperation(description="My description.")
    @ManagedOperationParameters({
        @ManagedOperationParameter(name = "myParam", description = "My param description.")
    })
    public void foo(String someParameter);
}
```

My bean appears in jconsole, but it does not display the associated metadata, so I don't get an operation description or correct parameter name/description.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748087/spring-prototypes-and-mbeanexporter

Comment: When we are using those spring classes we set the annotations on the implementation methods, _not_ in the interface.  We don't use MXBean interfaces.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Gray: with this particular bean, I register it manually with that MBean exporter. At the time, I provide a name explicitly.

Comment: @Gray: btw, this is not related to my previous post. The previous post was about avoiding prototype instantiation.

Comment: @Gray: just tried with the annotations on the implementation method rather than the interface. Still doesn't work.

Comment: This matches our config exactly.  Strange.  You see the bean, you see the `foo()` operation, just that it's description and params are not available?

Comment: @Gray: exactly right. And I had a look through other built-in beans too (like those in java.lang) to see if I could see any evidence of annotations being read. Nothing :( btw, this is Java 6, Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, jconsole 1.6.0_26-b03.

Comment: Well the java.lang stuff probably doesn't use the spring annotations.  :-)  But you do see descriptions with other beans.

Comment: Stupid suggestion:  Any chance one of the beans is coming from somewhere else?  From another part of the context?  Have you tried making your bean names more unique?

Comment: @Gray: no chance, I'm afraid. There's only the two instances of the bean and I append the hash code to their name to ensure uniqueness. I have debugged through the code several times to make sure it's doing what I think it is, and it is.

Comment: Might be interesting to try to export using my SimpleJmx library as opposed to Spring to see if it has the same problem.  Depends how desperate you are.  :-) http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/